# Angular - how to one-way link two input values?

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, oneway

I have a large HTML form with lots of text. There are some duplicated input fields and customer wants to prefill bottom fields with values filled earlier, but without affecting already filled inputs.

Think about it as in the following scenario: you are filling a licence agreement and enter your name in a textbox. Then at the end of the document there again is an input box for your name next to signature field. This name field should be filled with the value you entered before. But there might be situations when another person will sign the document on your behalf, and then both fields will differ.

Obviously, I cannot just link both fields to single model because the bottom field must be independent. It should be changed only if the top field changes, but not vice versa.

**Is there any way I can achieve such one way binding for both fields, but keeping them linked to separate models?**

I'd prefer some trick that can be used inside HTML to avoid coding Javascript logic, if possible, because this HTML form is stored in database as a document template and I'd like to avoid adding lots of Javascript to it.

Comment: you anyway include angular? why bother about including short script

Comment: @Petr: Because if I create scripts, specific to HTML template, I'll have to store them also in the database together with the HTML template. I want to avoid custom scripts for these templates as much as possible, and until now it was enough to have a single controller for every kind of template without controller knowing what HTML code it is being attached to.

Comment: store javascript inside html

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/OMkEduftGjf3H8L4AGlx?p=preview this may help -)

Comment: Thanks, yes, this works for simple inputs. It might get tricky with <select> tags, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<input ng-change="secondVal = firstVal" ng-model="firstVal">
...
<input ng-model="secondVal">
```

Comment: @Martin said that he want to still update the bottom value when the top value change. This will not be usefull in his usecase.

Comment: Oh, corrected the answer as per your comment Okazari.

Comment: Yeah, this will be cleaner without calling a function for this usecase. If he have more than one other value to update he will need to use a function.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using ng-change to update the other value :

**HTML**

```
<input ng-change="updateNameBot()" ng-model="nameTop">
<input ng-model="nameBot">
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.updateNameBot = function(){
      $scope.nameBot = $scope.nameTop;
}
```